# Kubernetes permissions for Helm 3 install to specific namespace

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup a user that will have permissions to install using Helm 3 in to a specific namespace.  (For my CI/CD system.)

For example, if the user tries to run a `helm upgrade --install` with `--namespace=dev` then it works just fine.  But if they try `--namespace=test` it will fail.

But I finding my self overwhelmed by the options.  When creating a role you have to pick `apiGroups`, `resources` and `verbs`.  I see a resource called `deployments`, but I have read that secret access is also needed.  I have done some googling, but most hits are about configuring Helm 2 (with tiller).

**What are the minimum Kubernetes permissions needed to install using Helm 3?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kubernetes,  best practice is to ensure that your application is operating in the scope that you have specified that is why you have to grant role to user or application-specific service account. Read more about service account permissions [in the official Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#service-account-permissions).

To restrict a user's access to a particular namespace, you can use either the  `edit`  or the  `admin`  role. If your charts create or interact with Roles and Rolebindings, you'll want to use the  `admin`  ClusterRole.

Additionally, you may also create a RoleBinding with  `cluster-admin`  access. Granting a user  `cluster-admin`  access at the namespace scope provides full control over every resource in the namespace, including the namespace itself.

For this example, we will create a user with the  `edit`  Role. First, create the namespace:

```
$ kubectl create namespace your-namespace
```

Now, create a RoleBinding in that namespace, granting the user the  `edit`  role.

```
$ kubectl create rolebinding steve-edit
    --clusterrole edit \​
    --user steve \​
    --namespace your-namespace
```

This command will create rolebinding `steve-edit`. This rolebinding grants the permissions defined in a clusterrole `edit` to a user `steve` for namespace `your-namespace`

`Edit` is default clusterrole which allows read/write access to most objects in a namespace. It does not allow viewing or modifying roles or rolebindings.

Take a look: [rbac-namespace-helm](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/rbac/#example-grant-a-user-readwrite-access-to-a-particular-namespace).

Read about clusterroles: [rbac-clusteroles](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy/testdata/cluster-roles.yaml), [kubernetes-authorization](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/authorization/rbac/).

You can also grant specific user read/write access at the cluster scope, so you will be able to install helm in any namespace. You have to grant the user either  `admin`  or  `cluster-admin`  access.

Read more here: [cluster-scope-rbac-helm](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/rbac/#example-grant-a-user-readwrite-access-at-the-cluster-scope).

Comment: So really it comes down to what your Helm chart is doing to Kubernetes.  If you are changing roles and such, you need `admin` or `cluster-admin`, but if not, you may be able to get away just having `edit`.  Thank you for the fantastic answer!

Comment: Also, I did not realize that cluster roles could be limited to only work in one namespace.  That is really useful!